# Mysql, AVG and Count question

Tags: mysql

```
ID,    rating_id , rating_num

33100,   '4028',      2, 
33099,   '4041',      2, 
33098,   '1889',      4, 
33097,   '1889',      5, 
33096,   '4050',      2,
33095,   '8578',      2, 
33094,   '8578',      4,
33093,   '8578',      5,
33093,   '8578',      5,
```

Guys 3 questions

1) How can i see which rating_id  has received more than three counts of rating_num ? (Answer: 8578)

2) How can i see the average rating_num of each rating_id ?

3) How can i see the average rating_num of each rating_id WHICH received more than three counts of rating_num ? ( Answer: 4 )

Thanks for replying the classs attender of Mysql4dumbmies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1

```
select rating_id
    from YourTable
    group by rating_id
    having count(*) > 3
```

2

```
select rating_id, avg(rating_num) as average_rating
    from YourTable
    group by rating_id
```

3

```
select rating_id, avg(rating_num) as average_rating
    from YourTable
    group by rating_id
    having count(*) > 3
```